# SetDllDirectory does not cascade, so dependency DLLs cannot be loaded

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, setdlldirectory

I execute an exe from a directory, say, "C:/test"
The DLLs are in the directory "C:/test/dlls" so, in this exe, I call:

```
SetDllDirectory("C:/test/dlls");
```

Then I call

```
lib1 = LoadLibrary("lib1.dll)
```

and

```
ptrType pr = (ptrType) ::GetProcAddress(lib1, "test")
```

`lib1.dll` needs other DLLs that are in the directory "C:/test/dlls", but when I execute `pr(...)` got from `GetProcAddress`, I get an error:

> "The program can't start because lib2.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

If I move `lib2.dll` to "C:/test", it is found.
That means that `SetDllDirectory()` is valid only for the loading of the first DLL.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but I have to ask anyway: what is the motivation of putting the DLLs in a "dlls" subdirectory of your application folder? On Windows, [the application's directory is the application bundle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110620-00/?p=10393/), so you should just put the DLLs there. This also prevents you from being vulnerable to security issues, like rogue DLLs being placed in the current directory and erroneously loaded.

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect. Some other code, probably in lib1, is reverting your call to `SetDllDirectory`. Put all the DLLs in the same directory as the executable and move on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: no, lib1 does not revert the call

Comment: @CodyGray: because we have something like 70 DLLs and we would like to separate them. But probably you're right, we should avoid it as it is only for a "nice to see" reason

Comment: Separate the DLLs from what? Other executable modules? For what particular purpose? It's not like the application directory is user-visible.

Comment: If it doesn't revert the call then it does something else to avoid using the modified search directory. You have misdiagnosed the issue. Anyway, the solution is trivial. All DLLs in the executable directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This *should* work. `SetDllDirectory` does "cascade" and thus will affect how dependent DLLs are loaded. Basically, `SetDllDirectory` allows you to modify the process's [default search order for DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications), and whatever changes are made to this affect the entire process, including any DLLs that may be loaded into that process. This search order is also used by Windows when it implicitly loads dependencies for child processes.

However, there is a fatal flaw in `SetDllDirectory`, as called out in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx):

> Each time the `SetDllDirectory` function is called, it replaces the directory specified in the previous `SetDllDirectory` call.

If some other code in your process is calling `SetDllDirectory`, then it is undoing your first call. If it is code in lib1.dll that does this before it attempts to load lib2.dll, then the attempt to load lib2.dll will fail.

Now, granted, this is bad behavior on the part of lib1.dll. DLLs are [guests in the application process and therefore should not go changing the carpet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091202-00/?p=15823). But not all code out there is well-behaved, which makes this a fragile strategy.

Another way this could go wrong would be if lib1.dll loads lib2.dll by calling [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179.aspx) and passing one of the many flags that  override the default search order, like `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR`.

The *best* solution is to put all of the DLLs that you depend on in the application directory. On Windows, [the application's directory is the application bundle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110620-00/?p=10393/), so this is the best place to put them. Users should never be digging through this directory, so "cluttering it up" is not a concern. It solves all sorts of problems, including the dependency-injection attack where someone puts a DLL of the same name in the current directory. (You can prevent this type of attack by calling `SetDllDirectory` and passing an empty string to remove the current directory from the search order, but now we're back to problem #1. If you have a guest in your house that's modifying the DLL search order, this isn't a reliable fix for the security issue. If you put the DLLs in the application directory, they will be found *first* before the current directory is ever searched, closing the attack vector before it can ever be exploited.)

If you have a *really good reason* for putting the DLLs in a different directory, then you have a limited number of options.

You can't use `AddDllDirectory` as the above-quoted documentation goes on to advise, because you don't control the code in lib1.dll and therefore can't modify it to call `LoadLibraryEx` with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS` flag.

Loading lib1.dll by specifying the full path won't work, because "If a DLL has dependencies, the system searches for the dependent DLLs as if they were loaded with just their module names. This is true even if the first DLL was loaded by specifying a full path."

This leaves you with the options of either [using DLL redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600.aspx), or adding information about your dependencies in your application's [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375365.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed answer. I will try to convince my team to do as you all have suggested me here. Putting the DLLs in another directory seems to be a **very** stupid solution

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph, do you mean to discuss child **processes**? Looks like a single process here and I don't think child processes inherit modified dll search path.

Comment: Yes, `SetDllDirectory` affects the entire process *and* all child processes. Or, at least, it affects how Windows *implicitly* loads DLLs that child processes depend upon. It has no effect when the child process calls `LoadLibrary`. Sloppy wording either way, I suppose. Will fix. @david

Comment: It's a bit more complex. Our exe is injecting a library into a running process. Also, I'm quite new in the company so I still don't have a clear idea on what's going on.

Comment: Injecting a DLL into another running process? You aren't the only one who hasn't a clear idea of what's going on. I can't imagine very many legitimate reasons that an app would want to do that. Malware purposes mostly spring to mind. Why would you need to do that? Do you not control the other process? What is this application?

Comment: Sorry, cannot say more. Thanks again for the answer

Comment: @CodyGray Well, I did not know that. Quite interesting.

Comment: `SetDefaultDllDirectories` is for alleviating some concerns however I don't know how a replaced DLL would not always be a threat vector